# Kafka Streams - Multiple Joins and Number of threads in a single instance

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a use case to do multiple joins on the two topics,

Lets say, I have topic A (2 partitions) and topic B (2 partitions) and running single instance of KafkaStreams application.

I have use case to find breaks, left miss and right miss between the two topics, so I am performing following 3 operations,

```
A.join(B)
B.leftJoin(A)
A.leftJoin(B)
```

As per the documentation, there will be two tasks (max(2,2)) will be created for each topology and a total of 6 tasks, i.e,

```
 1. A.join(B)  - two tasks created - each task is assigned two
    partitions 
 2. B.leftJoin(A) - two tasks created - each task is assigned
    two partitions 
 3. A.leftJoin(B) - two tasks created - each task is
    assigned two partitions
```

Since i am running a single instance, to scale up, i am planning to configure num.stream.threads=6 and each thread will be assigned one task.

is my above understanding correct?  Please correct me if i am mistake.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 1):

From confluent documentation:

> The default implementation provided by Kafka Streams is
>   DefaultPartitionGrouper, which assigns each task with at most one
>   partition for each of the source topic partitions; therefore, the
>   generated number of tasks is equal to the largest number of partitions
>   among the input topics.  [1]

So if you aren't overriding `partition.grouper` config, the number of tasks should be 2.

Links:
[1] http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#optional-configuration-parameters